# Meditation techniques used in different branches/traditions of Buddhism

Tags: theravada, mahayana, meditation-recommendation, vajrayana

What are some meditation techniques used in different branches/traditions/vehicles of Buddhism?

Please provide the name of the technique, names of branches/traditions/vehicles that apply this technique, and recommended references that can allow to read more about the technique.

In case you want to provide information about what is the point or the most distinguishing feature of the technique, please do it in a few sentences and avoid extended discussion.

Comment: This is a massive topic.  Each vehicle has it own sub schools which in turn have their own sub sub schools that have their own meditation techniques.  For instance, you have Mahayana, then you have Zen, then you have shikantaza and koan meditation.  There's even variations within those.  And don't even get me started on Tibetan Buddhism!  A couple of books that might help - Mahayana Buddhist Meditation (Kiyota) and Theravada Mediation (King).  I could go on for pages on books on Tibetan techniques.

Comment: @Michay. As Neko has already mentioned, this topic is extremely big and very broad. It would be great if you could narrow it down, so its easier to answer.

Comment: Would it work if I asked about a list of names of all meditation techniques used by different branches of Buddhism, with information in which branches each of them used? It would be analogous to this question: http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/10412/could-someone-provide-a-list-of-all-buddhist-schools/10415#10415 It could be a community wiki.

Comment: @Lanka If any answer to this question would be too long to post here, would it work to ask for recommended references to places where this question is answered elsewhere (e.g. online, and/or in specific books like the ones mention by neko)?

Comment: @ChrisW. I think that sounds like a good idea. Then the references will contain the detailed answers to meditation techniques. As Michau proposed, we can turn this into a *community wiki*.

Comment: @Michau. How does this sound. Would that be okay, to ask for recommended references instead?

Comment: I edited the question, what do you think? I think some comments may be needed, as for example, different traditions may have different techniques with the same name. But I made it clear that such comments should be brief, and that an open-ended comparison of the techniques should be avoided.

Comment: Question is now reopened.

Comment: I answered here in relation to meditations techniques Tibetans emphasize. Some of them belong to both perfection vehicle and secret mantra vehicle : http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/11936/text-request-tibetan-buddhism/11946#11946